# Run scalable Service in GKE with fixed Domain and Port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, url, cloudflare

I've a shipped app where a URL is hardcoded "upload.mydomain.io:123123/myRoute".

This DNS points to an VM where an NGINX distributes the traffic to services. 
Now I need to put a highly scalable service in front of the VM, WITHOUT having the possibility to change the hardcoded URL. I've tried so far:

- Cloud Functions
- App Engine
- Cloud Run
- My own Kubernetes Cluster.

As an DNS Distributer I use Cloudflare, where I also tried to do something with Page Rules.

Functions -> No Domain in EU

Cloud Run -> Only Port 80

App Engine -> Only Port 8080

Kubernetes Ingress -> I can put my Domain on, also with the port as Service port, but then in the URL the port is gone

This is my Kubernetes Manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: myApp-api
  name: myApp-api
spec:
  replicas: 3
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: myApp-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myApp-api
        env:
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: production
        image: eu.gcr.io/myApp-123/myApp-api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 21337
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myApp-api-service
  name: myApp-api-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: myApp-api-port
    port: 21337
    targetPort: 21337
  selector:
    app: myApp-api
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myApp-api-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - upload.myDomain.io
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: upload.myDomain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: myApp-api-service
          servicePort: myApp-api-port
```

Is it possible somehow to create this route with some service?

Comment: Can you give some details on how are you putting a Kubernetes cluster in front of your VM?

Comment: I have a kubernetes Cluster which receives the request (Express.JS backend Pod) and if conditions are true, it pipes the request to the VM.
I also edited my Answer to show the cluster configs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) services to [map external services within the cluster](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services), this way, you'd see your service as a cluster-local address (represented by a Service), which will be relaying requests to your external service.

Alternatively, you can user an specific type of service called [`ExternalName`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname), that also does the same relaying only using DNS names instead of addresses.